# Change the Label in JavaFX to different values

Tags: java, javafx, label

This doesn't change my label. Only first one runs and others don't change. In Java swing it worked but in Javafx doesn't.

```
package vehicalservice;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXProgressBar;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author lahir
 */
public class SplashNewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    @FXML
    private JFXProgressBar pbarLoad;
    @FXML
    private Label lblLoad = new Label();

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        new SplashScreen().start();
    }    

    class SplashScreen extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i <=100;i++){
                        Thread.sleep(40); 
                        if(i<=30){
                           lblLoad.setText("Initilizing Components...");
                       }else if(i<=50){

                           lblLoad.setText("Initializing Database Connection...");
                           //new mainCLass().openDB();
                       }else if(i<=80){
                           lblLoad.setText("Initializing User Interface...");                           
                       }else{
                           lblLoad.setText("Please wait...");         
                       }
                }
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Parent root=null;
                        try {

                            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
                            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                            Stage stage = new Stage();
                            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                            stage.setScene(scene);
                            stage.show();

                            stackPane.getScene().getWindow().hide();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            //Logger.getLogger(SplashController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }                       
                    }
                });

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(SplashController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: provide some minimalist working example.

Comment: please don't use `Thread.sleep` in a JavaFx application. It pause the entire UI.

Comment: i have another cool solution use Fade animation it change your text with some cool animation and also by specified time!!  if you want i can show you an example leave me a reply for it!

Comment: @user55924 can you please email me lahiru.nc@gmail.com

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, and can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Thread.sleep(40);`, you are actually stopping the JavaFX Application Thread and there will be no GUI updates. As it is pointed out in the comments, you should not suspend the application thread.

You could do the update from a different thread:

```
Task<Void> loadTask = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(40);
            String text = "";
            if (i <= 30)
                text = "Initilizing Components...";
            else if (i <= 50)
                text = "Initializing Database Connection...";
            else if (i <= 80)
                text = "Initializing User Interface...";
            else
                text = "Please wait...";

            String finalText = text;
            Platform.runLater(() -> lblLoad.setText(finalText));
        }
        return null;
    }
};


new Thread(loadTask).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javafx.animation.Timeline` for periodic events:

```
int counter=0;

Timeline doEvery40sec = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(40), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
if(counter==0) 
        lblLoad.setText("Initilizing Components...");
    }else if(counter==1){
        lblLoad.setText("Initializing Database Connection...");
    }else if(counter==2){
        lblLoad.setText("Initializing User Interface...");                           
    }else if(counter==3)
        lblLoad.setText("Please wait...");
counter++;  
    }
}));
fiveSecondsWonder.setCycleCount(4);
fiveSecondsWonder.play();
```